# Compile time error while gradle build when using protobuf with android studio

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

While integrating protobuf into my android project, I am getting this error during gradle build:

```
Type com.google.protobuf.SourceContextOrBuilder is defined multiple times: /Users/kchaubal/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4af300e60802588311eb01ecc52e7bea/jetified-protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar:com/google/protobuf/SourceContextOrBuilder.class, /Users/kchaubal/Dev/GitHubRepo/RPCExample/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/google/protobuf/SourceContextOrBuilder.class
```

This is how my grade file looks like

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.29.0'
    protobuf 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.29.0' 
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.29.0' 
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3'
}

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
}
plugins {
    javalite {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
    }
    grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.29.0'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.builtins {
            remove java
        }
        task.plugins {
            javalite { }
            grpc { option 'lite' }
        }
    }
}
files("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/proto")
}
```

I am a newbie with protobuf so any kind of help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

dependencies {
  ...
  protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1'
}

Comment: In documentation: 
https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin